# AJAX Call not returning data

Tags: php, jquery, html

Can someone tell me why the div called tellme is showing only showing something for half a second.. or less and then just doing nothing? I have tried everything and just can't get the code to work. It is funny because I have the exact same code on my other page and it works with no problems what so ever, I am trying to call an AJAX call and it is just not working and its not making the div called tellme anything, it's just keeping it blank...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fireWorkerFixed(userid)
{
    // Create our XMLHttpRequest object
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
    var url = "http://private.com/fire_worker.php";
    var id = userid;
    var vars = "userid="+id;
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    // Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    // Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var return_data = hr.responseText;
            document.getElementById('tellme').innerHTML = return_data;
        }
    }
    // Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
    hr.send(vars); // Actually execute the request
    document.getElementById('tellme').innerHTML = "<div class='alert alert-info'>Please wait, Processing request...</div>";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Just before anyone asks.. there were no errors in the JS console.

Comment: What do you mean by 'doing nothing',.. what is the required outcome?

Comment: Some text to go into the tellme div...

Comment: is error reporting turned on on the server side? It might be emitting errors which have been suppressed if error reporting is turned off.

Comment: But what happens now, is it just displaying 'Please wait' all of the time?

Comment: It's not displaying anything.

Comment: The content of my PHP file is <?phpdie('Ran With AJAX :)');?> how can that error?

Comment: `<?phpdie('Ran With AJAX :)');?>` how are you not seeing the syntax error? It should be:           `<?php die('Ran With AJAX '));?>` Note the space after <?php, also note how I close the 'Ran With AJAX' string, before the closing parentheses.

Comment: @mikeO. you have an extra parentheses

Comment: @YerkoPalma you are right. Liam, you need to remove the extra parentheses also

Comment: @LiamHardy tell us if that fix your problem

Comment: This is the sort of case where it's a good idea to hit the target of the AJAX call with a browser to ensure that the results are what you're expecting.  mike O. is right, you have a syntax error in your PHP file, and if you would have hit that PHP file with your browser, it would have displayed a blank page.  Hence, you get no results from your AJAX call.